# How do i get Option Selected Data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get the text and the value but i want to get another tag

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value <---will get the value

this.options[this.selectedIndex].text   <---will get the text
```

I want to get the data_id from this option

```
<option value="L W12 6.3 quattro" data-id="200480476">L W12 6.3 quattro</option>
```

I have tried:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].data-id
```

and didn't work

I am sorry i will add more info... I am using this on nested forms in ruby on rails and have an on change event set up for it:

```
<select id="shipment_vehicles_attributes_0_style" name="shipment[vehicles_attributes][0][style]" onchange="getStylesId(this.id,this.options[this.selectedIndex].data-id)"><option value="">Select A Style</option><option value="Base" data-id="9058">Base</option></select>
```

Can i use jquery in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags suggest that you are using jQuery. Then you can do this:

`var attr = $('option:selected').attr( "data-id" );`

Answer (score 0):

you can use .attr() of jquery.

```
    $("option").attr('data_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery methods mentioned work just fine.  But if you want to use vanilla JS, which is typically faster, then you need to use the `getAttribute` method:

```
  var x = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  alert( x.getAttribute('data-id') );
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6o4y36j/1/).